# Вывод комментариев на PHP для текущего пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы в БД: `users` и `comments`.

Таблицы связаны JOIN-ом. Комментарии выводятся, всё работает. Проблема лишь в том, что из базы выводятся все зарегистрированные пользователи.

Например: заходит В. Пупкин, написать - "привет", а из базы выводятся все: и Васи, и Коли, и Вани с сообщением "привет". В общем, дублируются комментарии.

Я так понимаю, нужно написать проверку на то, что пользователь действительно вошел на сайт, чтобы комментарий схватывал текущую сессию. В БД добавил `current_user_id`, а в php `WHERE current_user_id='$_SESSION[login]'`.

Не хватает проверки или еще чего-то?

```
$date = $_POST["date"];
  $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
  $text_comment = $_POST["text_comment"];
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $page_id = $_POST["page_id"];
  $art_id = $_POST["art_id"];
  $current_user_id = $_POST["current_user_id"];

        $text_comment = htmlspecialchars($text_comment);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($name); 


        $date = date("d.m.Y в H:i:s");

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","12345","base");
  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`date`, `user_id`, `text_comment`, `name`, `page_id`, `art_id`, `current_user_id`) VALUES (NOW(), '$user_id', '$text_comment', '$name', '$page_id', '$art_id', '$current_user_id')");
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

**index.php**

```
 <div style="display:none" id="comment_form">
                    <form action="comment.php" method="post" name="comment" >
                        <textarea name="text_comment" cols="30" rows="5" ></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="1"  />
                        <input name="send" type="submit" value="Добавить"  class="f-r btn" onclick="this.disabled=true; comment.submit();" />
                    </form>
                </div>



$page_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users JOIN comments ON users.login = comments.user_id WHERE art_id='$_SESSION[login]' ORDER BY date DESC" ,$db); 
$comment = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do{
echo "<div class='comment'><h5 style='font-weight:normal;'>".$comment['date']."</h5><strong>".$comment['login']."</strong><br><br>".$comment['text_comment']."<br></div>";
}while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: добавьте тег mysql, удалите теги css и html

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

добавьте в таблицу `comments` столбик `author_id` и при добавлении комментария сохраняйте туда ID пользователя который его добавил.

в таблице `users` должен быть столбик который хранит ID пользователей. у каждого пользователя ID должен быть уникальным. обычно для этого столбик под ID делают PRIMARY KEY + AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: все эти столбики были, как сохранять id пользователей при добавлении комментария, можете подробнее описать?

Comment: если у вас есть авторизация перед комментированием, то при каждом заходе на сайт проверяется авторизация и сравнивается с определенным пользователем в БД. т. е. опознается конкретный пользователь из таблицы `user`. остается только получить его ID на основе данных авторизации

Comment: если же у вас нет авторизации, то добавлении первого комментария создавайте запись в БД с данными пользователя и генерируйте из этих данных и метки времени sha1-хеш который сохраняйте в новый столбик в таблице `user` и ставьте этот хеш кукой пользователю. потом при добавлении каждого нового комментария проверяете есть ли такая кука и щите по ней пользователя и получаете его ID в базе данных

Comment: Авторизация перед комментированием есть, и приветствие тоже. Сейчас немного изменил код, теперь вместо присвоения к примеру - "привет" всем имеющимся в базе пользователям выводится самый первый из них. В самой БД не происходит подстановки значений из таблицы users где у user1 id=1, у user2 id=2 и т.д. в таблицу comments в поле user_id - там только 0 и 1 подставляется. И только если вручную изменить в самой БД на 3 тогда он выведет комментарий пользователя user3. Понимаю, что может очень элементарные вещи, но что не хватает чтобы он подставлял значения из одной таблицы в другую автоматом?

Comment: автоматом подставлять не будет. надо чтобы ваш код определял ID комментирующего и добавлял этот ID вместе с комментарием

Comment: очень рекомендую прочитать какой-нить учебник по PHP. вам очень не хватает элементарных знаний. советую "PHP 5 в подлиннике. второе издание" авторы Котеров и Костарев

Answer (score 0):

```
$myid = '1';

$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE idUser='$myid'");
while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) {
    echo $comment[text];
}
```

**myid** - это ID пользователя которому надо вывести

**idUser** - это строка в БД в которой будет находиться ID пользователя, который которому необходимо вывести этот комментарий

**text** - строка в БД в которой будет храниться сам текст комментария

Answer (score -1):

Предположим, что есть две таблички MySQL со структурой:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `comment_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_comment_id` INT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Таблицы связаны по **user_id** и также **`comments`** связана с собой по **parent_comment_id**. Т.е. каждый коммент связан с пользователем и неким родительским комментом.

Тогда зная **parent_comment_id** несложно получить все дочерние комменты:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments`
WHERE parent_comment_id = '<some_comment_id>';
```

Либо же имея`IdentityService` с методом `getLoggedUserId()` (узнать ID текущего залогиненного пользователя), можно  написать что-то вроде:

```
SELECT childred.* FROM `comments` AS childred
  JOIN `comments` AS parent
    ON parent.comment_id =
      childred.parent_comment_id
        JOIN users
          ON parent.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.user_id = <logged_user_id>;
```

... и получить все дочерние комменты для пользователя.